# Inject divs with jQuery while keeping word distance from specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I need to inject some divs (that contain links to other articles in the site) in the content of a page. The rules in order to inject these divs are pretty tricky:

- They need to be injected always after a paragraph.
- There needs to be a minimum amount of words before the first injected div.
- There needs to be a minimum amount of words before the previous injected div and the one that is being inserted right now.
- There needs to be a minimum amount of words between the currently injected div and some specific elements in the content.

I have created a function that aspires to do the things mentioned above and looks like this:

```
  function elementProximityCheck(paragraphOffset, wordSpace, elSelector) {

    var elementsToCheck = ['figure', 'blockquote'];
    var wordCounter, paragraphOffsetMin, paragraphOffsetMax;

    wordCounter = 0;
    paragraphOffsetMin = paragraphOffset-1;
    do {
      wordCounter += numOfWords(paragraphOffsetMin, elSelector);
      paragraphOffsetMin -= 1;
    } while (wordCounter < wordSpace);

    wordCounter = 0;
    paragraphOffsetMax = paragraphOffset;
    do {
      wordCounter += numOfWords(paragraphOffsetMax, elSelector);
      paragraphOffsetMax += 1;
    } while (wordCounter < wordSpace);

    $(elSelector).slice(paragraphOffsetMin, paragraphOffsetMax + 1).each(function () {
      for (var elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < elementsToCheck.length; elementIndex++) {
        if ($(this).is(elementsToCheck[elementIndex])) {
          paragraphOffset = elementProximityCheck(paragraphOffsetMax, wordSpace, elSelector);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });

    return paragraphOffset;
  }
```

This function is called after I have identified the first paragraph that meets the 2nd condition above.

The main idea is that I search backward and forward for an element of the elementsToCheck array and if such an element is found, the function calls itself recursively with a new paragraph index (which is the paragraph that I used as a bound in the previous execution).

The problem is that this thing does not work and I can't really figure out why. Any insights (or alternative solutions) will be highly appreciated.

Edit:

Below you can find a JSFiddle implementation of my code along with the extra function that I'm using to count the words.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qpuhf9yb/)

Edit 2: Using the JSFiddle, the paragraphIndex that I'm getting back is always the same paragraph that I provide. In theory, the code should move/increase the paragraph index when a figure or blockquote is found in the "wordSpace proximity" of the current paragraph element.

For example, if the wordSpace variable is 60, then assuming that we start looking from the 3rd paragraph (paragraphIndex = 2), in the first execution of the function, the paragraphOffsetMin should be 0, paragraphOffsetMax should be 3, and then it should call itself with 3 as the paragraphIndex. In the recursive call, the paragraphOffsetMin should be 2 and paragraphOffsetMax should be 4 and this is what should be returned in the end.

What I'm basically trying to do is inject the elements using specific "word distances" between them and also "avoiding the hurdles of blockquotes/figures. I suspect that there are better algorithms than the one that I provided though.

Comment: Can you please describe in what way "*this thing does not work*"? Also, why the constraints of the 'minimum number of words in various rules; it *feels* like an artificial constraint to fit a particular design requirement that might be better solved in some other way.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for taking a look at it. Edit 2 is an attempt of answering your questions.